# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libpq.lib'

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++

I'm trying to connect to a windows postgresql database from my Visual C++ project.

I downloaded the Graphical installer by BigSQL for 9.5.9 from here: https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/

I have set the following properties correctly in my C++ project(based on a tutorial on how to setup postgress connection from c++ program)

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

And Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies is set to libpq.lib.

When I try to compile it I get the following error message:
LNK1104 cannot open file 'libpq.lib'

I cannot find libpq.lib anywhere on my machine. Should this file have been included by the installer? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, the default install location for PostgreSQL 12 is:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib\libpq.lib
```